# Laravel inserting normal image, value become null

Tags: php, laravel

I am Learning at the moment. But got one problem. I have build a database:

[image]

and my controller code is:

UploadController.php

```
public function upload(Request $request, Task $task)
{

        $task->image = Request::get('image');
        $task->save();
        return redirect('/');

}
```

TaskController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

        $task->delete();
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else
    {
        $task->description = Request::get('description');
        $task->save();
        return redirect('/'); 
    }       
}

public function upload(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

        $task->delete();
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else
    {
    $task->image = Request::get('image');
    $task->save();
    return redirect('/');
    }       
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Edit the Task</h1>



<form method="POST" action="/task/{{ $task->id }}">

<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="description" class="form-control">{{$task->description }}</textarea>    
</div>

<form action="{{ URL::to('upload') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Select image to upload:</label>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Insert" name="insert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
    <img class="user_avatar" src="{{url('public/uploads/test.jpg')}}">      
</form>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Update task</button>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Update task</button>
</div>
```

These are my code, when I try to insert an image in to my database, it become null and self create another set of null data. How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

[image]

This is my database at the moment

[image]

This is the inside value of the image
[image]

Comment: can you put only those functions which are being  used on this action.? and route as well

Comment: As I can see, your file input has name attribute "file" and not image. Anyway, if you'll change property name to "image", your code probably won't work, because you'll need to save this image somewhere first and then store the file link to your database. Read more on official site - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul   I have cut to only showing my function code. Please have a look thank you.

Comment: Have you tested if `request('image')` even returns a value?

Comment: @CHUNHINHO where is your route.? because in you code says 2   upload function need to check that

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul I try to put my route in here, but it did show. I will leave it in command.

Comment: Route::get('/task','TasksController@add');
Route::post('/task','TasksController@create');

Route::get('/task/{task}','TasksController@edit');
Route::post('/task/{task}','TasksController@update');
Route::post('/task/{task}', 'TasksController@upload');
Route::post('/upload','TasksController@upload');

Route::get('/task/create','TasksController@create');

Route::post('/tasksaction','TasksController@storeTask');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```php
public function upload(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

        $task->delete();
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else
    {
    $task->image = \Storage::disk('public')->put('image', $request->file('image'));
    $task->save();
    return redirect('/');
    }       
}
```

and

**filesystems.php**

inside

```php
   'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path() . '/uploads',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

inside blade

```html
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="file" name="image" id="file">
```

change `name="image"` then only you can get `$request->file('image')`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206950/discussion-on-answer-by-kamlesh-paul-laravel-inserting-normal-image-value-becom). Please be sure to [edit] the answer with all relevant information.

Comment: @CodyGray actually answer is correct but he have some other issue as well , we will discuss with chat thank you

Comment: If there is a different issue, then CHUN HIN HO should ask a new question. He can link it here, so that you can try to help there as well.

Comment: @CodyGray okay.

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry about that. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @CodyGray I got a question about stack overflow website, Can you teach me?I have try to move to a chat, but it said I don't have enough point or something. So, how can I move to a chat then I can ask for help?

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to participate in chat, @eduu1688. Privileges for this site are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). For chat, it's [20 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat). What happened here is that I (as a moderator) got a notification that there were an excessively large number of comments on this post (over 30, in this case), and I used a built-in tool to move those comments to chat since, as the auto-comment indicated, [comments are not meant for extended discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: You don't have the privileges to create your own chat room, and normally you wouldn't be able to talk in chat, but I *believe* that since I created this chat room by moving the comments there, you should be able to participate.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. But in the post that I have link to this one. I am facing the same problem. So what can I do about that?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to same image directly to db in BLOB field

```
$task->image = request('image')->encode('jpg', 80);
$task->save();
```

You can update the variables as suitable to you but the solution is in **encode** 
You can encode your image first like this

```
$b64 = base64_encode(request('image'));
```

Comment: I have give a try, but it said encode is null. So, what should I need to change to avoid null happen? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can not save image in database, you must move image to a folder and save address it in database and type column image must be varchar text.
change code to :

```
   public function storeTask()
{
    $task = new Task();
    $task->name = request('name');
    $task->description = request('description');
    $image = request->file('image');
    $extention = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $name = rand(1000, 9999) '.' . $extention;
    $path = public_path() . '/images/' . $name;
    $image->move($path);
    $task->image = $path;
    $task->save();
    return redirect('/task');
}
```

Comment: That's actually what I mean. I would like to store the path and then show in the test website. But the storing value become null. So I am not too sure how to change it not null.

Comment: @CHUNHINHO try my answer, you must upload image to a path and save path to database, a column that save path to it must be varchar or text

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
 $path = $request->file('image')->getRealPath();
 $image = file_get_contents($path);
 $base64 = base64_encode($image);
 $task->image = $base64;
 $task->save();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping it. I got an error which I am not sure what it is. Call to a member function getRealPath() on null . Can you help me with this?