# Cont: Url convert to string and save problem

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my previous post: [Laravel inserting normal image, value become null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59983014/laravel-inserting-normal-image-value-become-null)

Thank you for everyone giving me advise in previous post. Now I got another question. I would like to ask for help and teach me with this issues.

I currently want to save the image path in my database. As the previous post mentioned before. My database now is saving value 1 instead of the path. here is my function upload code.

```
public function upload(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

        $task->delete();
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else
    {
    $task->image = \Storage::disk('public')->put('image', Request::file('image'));

    $url = Storage::url('image');
    $url= urldecode(string ($url));
    $url->save();

    $task->save();
    return redirect('/');
    }
```

I also want to display this in my welcome.blade.php. So, what would I add and change?

This is all my code:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('welcome',compact('user'));
}

public function add()
{
    return view('add');
}

public function create(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();
    $task->description = Request::get('description');
    $task->user_id = Auth::id();
    $flagInserted = \Storage::disk('public')->put('image', Request::file('image'));

    $url = ''; 
    if ($flagInserted) {
        $url = Storage::url('image');
    }

    $task->image = $url;
    $duplicate = Task::where('description',Request::get('description'))->first();
    if($duplicate)
    {
        print_r("The data is exists");
    } 
    else
    {
        $task->save();
    } 
    return redirect('/'); 
}

public function edit(Task $task)
{

    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id == $task->user_id)
    {            
            return view('edit', compact('task'));
    }           
    else {
         return redirect('/');
     }              
}

public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

        $task->delete();
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else
    {
        $task->description = Request::get('description');
        $task->save();
        return redirect('/'); 
    }       
}

public function upload(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

        $task->delete();
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else
    {
        $flagInserted = \Storage::disk('public')->put('image', Request::file('image'));

    $url = ''; 
    if ($flagInserted) {
        $url = Storage::url('image');
    }

    $task->image = $url;
    $task->save();
    return redirect('/');
    }       

}

public function storeTask(){

    $task= new Task();

    $task->name = request('name');
    $task->description = request('description');
    $task->image = request('image');
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/task');

}
```

I have read the Laravel page. But not really sure and how can I able solve this problem.

Comment: You were using $task->image = \Storage::disk('public')->put('image', Request::file('image')), So it will return 1 or 0. That's why it is inserting 1 in your database. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below will return 1 or 0, if file is saved or not. That's why it is inserting 1 into your databse:

```
\Storage::disk('public')->put('image', Request::file('image'))
```

Once successfully saved, To fetch file url, you can use below code:

```
$url = \Storage::url('file.jpg');
```

So your code will be:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class FileuploadController extends Controller
    {
        //
        public function index() {
            return view('fileupload');
        }

        public function save(Request $request) {
            $image  = $request->file('image');
            $fileName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $img = \Image::make($image->getRealPath());
            $img->stream(); // <-- Key point

            $flagInserted = \Storage::disk('public')->put($fileName, $img);

            $url = '';
            if ($flagInserted) {
                $url = \Storage::url('app/public/' . $fileName);
            }
            dd($url);
        }
    }
```

If you face error like 'Class Image' not found that do as follow:

```
composer require intervention/image
```

You file will be saved in 'storage/app/public folder'.
If you file is not saved than please permission and allow permission your project folder.

Comment: Thank you. But I couldn't see in folder that image uploaded. So, is it not able to see or is it inside a storage/image file and hidden? Case I would also want to display it in welcome.blade.php.

Comment: You can read Laravel document, How file storage, read,  get url and all works. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have read. But still stuck in this part. So I will give another try to see any luck in that.

Comment: By default, this value is set to the storage/app directory. Therefore, it will store a file in storage/app/ folder. You can change storage path from filesystems configuration file i.e. config/filesystems.php

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I didn't notice. You use disck 'public' so your file will be saved in storage/app/public/ folder

Comment: Thank you. But in the public file have a blank file call image. I have uploaded the icon I am using as testing. But it doesn't show in the file. Is there I should change?

Comment: `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @Wahyu Krisitianto.  Thank you. This I have used and it link with it. But still only have a blank image file. So do you know where is my mistake?

Comment: @Pradeep Darjee  I changed to your code and got this error.    Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Comment: It is stroing blank file because, \Storage::disk('public')->put() accept parameter 1st parameter as file name and 2nd as file content and you are not passing file content

Comment: @eduu1688 Please dump your request. If you are not getting image file in request than it will set null in $image variable. That's why you are facing this error

Comment: I have made an update, and show all my code. I don't think I can delete request since is used in different function. what can I do?

Comment: @eduu1688 Please check updated answer. I have checked it and it is working properly. Using Laravel 6

Answer (score 0):

have you try this.? `Request::file` to `$request->file`

and

replce `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` to `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-uploads here you can see

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;` is imported not `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request`

```php
 public function upload(Request $request, Task $task)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {

            $task->delete();
            return redirect('/');
        } else {


            $task->image = \Storage::disk('public')->put('image', $request->image);

            $task->save();
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#storing-files

---

and to print image inside blade

you can use `Storage::url()` function on laravel

**EX :** `Storage::url($task->image) // here image value is coming from task table data`

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-urls

Comment: I have try it. It said static if I use $request->file which will give me an error. So I change to use Request::file for dynamic way

Comment: just put as it is and see you database columin don't put extra anything . i have test in my end it's working

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::file()   This is the error I got. I think we may better move to conversation to talk about this.

Comment: please import right libary `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` use this

Comment: I have tried that too. The database value become 1.

Comment: please put same code as i mentioned in answer ans replace you import Request from to that request which i mentioned in my answer

Comment: Thank you so much that you help me a lot. I will give another shot.